# Javascript: How to upload file onsubmit()?

Tags: javascript

I have a JSP page with `<form>` that uploads a file on submit.
But the **upload** function is not uploading any file to the server at the path */uploads*.

**HTML form:**

```
<form action="./index.jsp" onsubmit="uploadFile()">
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file " placeholder="Choose file" id="excelInput">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Run Profiling</button>
 </form>
```

**Javascript function to upload file:**

```
<script>
  function uploadFile(){
      let excel = document.getElementById("excelInput").files[0];  // file from input
      alert(excel);
      let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      let formData = new FormData();
        try{
              formData.append("excel", excel);                                
              req.open("POST", 'D:\\eclipse\\workspace\\Project2\\WebContent\\uploads');
              req.send(formData);
        }
        catch(e){ 
            alert(e);
        }
  }
  </script>
```

It is not going to the `catch()` section. But it isn't uploading either.
Is there anything missing ?

Comment: Maybe! you have to set the request header to multipart for sending files to server.
Yes, According to @AndreaGiammarchi you have to set prevention for the event and then use your own function

Comment: `onsubmit="uploadFile(event)"` so you can `event.preventDefault()` within the `uploadFile` function, but the main issue is that you are trying to POST a file to the filesystem `D:\\...` and that doesn't work. You need to post data to a server side end point that can handle POST requests.

Comment: 1) You need to prevent the default submit action, eg `onsubmit="uploadFile(); return false"`. 2) You should be posting to an actual URL. You cannot `POST` to a local directory

Comment: @RajpalSingh it's best not to set the `Content-type` header for `multipart/form-data` requests. When posting a `FormData` instance, it happens automatically

Answer (score 1):

The dupes seems to be very poor, so I post an answer.

You basically want to add an eventListener AND submit to a WEB SERVICE! Not a file location

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("uploadForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the submit

    let excel = document.getElementById("excelInput").files[0]; // file from input

    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let formData = new FormData();
    try {
      formData.append("excel", excel);
      req.open("POST", 'actual web address of a process that can handle xmlhttprequests');
      req.send(formData);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<form action="./index.jsp" id="uploadForm">
  <input type="file" class="form-control-file " placeholder="Choose file" id="excelInput">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Run Profiling</button>
</form>
```